how can I display categories with their elements?
I can't get a full-fledged tree of categories with their elements. That's how I'm trying to do it.:
{% if categories %}
    <div class="categories print">
        {% nav category in categories %}

                {% set prints = craft.entries().section('examples').categoryPrint(category).all() %}

                <div>
                    <strong>- CATEGORY_{{ category.id }}</strong>
                    {% for print in prints %}
                        <div style="padding: 0 0 0 25px">entry_{{print.id}}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                
                {% ifchildren %}
                    <div style="padding: 0 0 0 25px" class="sub-categories">
                        {% children %}
                    </div>
                {% endifchildren %}
                
        {% endnav %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

And my code works, but there is an inaccuracy that I do not know how to fix. The fact is that in the parent categories, the elements that belong to the child categories are displayed:

Please help me, how to solve this?

I believe you're looking for the Maintain hierarchy" checkbox on the category selector field. If you uncheck it, it'll ensure that relationships are only made with the single category you select and not its ancestors.


Unrelated, but if you get a chance, please could you also accept my answers to three of your other recent questions if they helped you:
How can I display a list of all the years for which there are entries?
How to filter elements by multiselect field via relatedTo
How do I authorize/register visitors on the site?

Thank you for your help. Your solutions helped a lot) Noted all the answers. They are extremely useful )))
